# Accessing Encrypted Archives

Tags: c++

I want to write a password program using C++ that will check the entered password against a file in an encrypted archive to see if it's correct. The archive is fingerprint accessible, but also has a backup password, which I'm assuming would be used. How do I get through the password barrier on the archive to check the file in the archive? Somehow I don't think `std::fstream` would do the trick.

***OS:*** Windows XP

***Compiler:*** MS Visual Studio 9.0 Express. I also have boost installed if needed.

***Encryption:*** biometric Protector Suite QL that came with my Sony VAIO, .ueaf extension on the archive

Comment: Is this an archive that you're building, or something pre-existing, like an encrypted Zip archive?  What do you mean by "fingerprint accessible" - biometrics?

Answer (score 2):

The crucial information missing is what kind of archive this is. Once you know that look for a library supporting this kind of archive. If it is no popular archive format and there is no library you need to find out what kind of encryption algorithm is used and how exactly it is applied, then use that information to decrypt the contents of the archive "by hand".